# Is there a way to create wealth deciles rather than quintiles in NFHS 5 household recode file?

Tags: r

In NFHS5 the wealth index has been created hv271 is the variable for the same in household recode. Also, based on the individual wealth score it creates wealth quintiles under the variable hv270 in household recode. I want to create wealth deciles rather than the quintiles. Is there a way to do it? Sharing an R code would be really helpful.

I want to analyse the observations around health and sanitation based on decile wealth figures.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.